# Detecting whether I have clicked within a shape drawn onto a Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am new to Android and am looking for a method that detects whether I have clicked on a shape drawn on a `Canvas`. I would also like to know whether I should do it in `onTouch()`.

Comment: How is your question's title related to the question itself?

Comment: How are you drawing your shape (what shape is it?). If it's a square/circle or other simple shape, it's just a question of doing the maths, i.e. for a circle, if you know the centre/radius you're fine.

Comment: I am taking a circle which gets generated taking random point as its Center but with fixed Radius.Detecting it for rectangle is easier but for a circle with random Center can be difficult.I need to kno how can i compare the point i have clicked with the circle circumference.